# Internet Explorer doesn't save the path from the open file dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, uploadify

I'm using Uploadify for uploading files. If the user starts the open file dialog (select files button with Uploadify) than a window appears where the user can navigate to his path and select a file which should be uploaded. Now the Internet Explorer doesn't store the path. If the user again clicks on the select files button he must again navigate to the desired folder.

I know that the user can upload multiple files at once but I was asked if the path can be stored for the next time (as e.g. Firefox behaves). Of course he could use another browser, but I want to know if there is anything I could do to instruct the Internet Explorer to save the path. Is there a setting in Uploadify for that or is there a JS snippet which could do that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely down to the browser there's nothing you can do through JavaScript to control this.

Answer (score 1):

The file open dialog behaviour is controlled by the browser itself, so there is nothing that can be done from javascript to change it.